# how to store target words in Python

Tags: python

I have a question in regard to how to store target words in the list.

I have a text file:

```
apple tree apple_tree
banana juice banana_juice
dinner time dinner_time
divorce lawyer divorce_lawyer
breakfast table breakfast_table
```

I would like read this file and store only nouns...but I am struggling with the code in Python.

```py
file = open("text.txt","r")
for f in file.readlines():
    words.append(f.split(" "))
```

I dont know how to split lines by white space and eliminate compounds with "_"...

```
list = [apple, tree, banana, juice, dinner, time...]
```

Comment: Note that you can also do `str.split('_')` to split, say, `"apple_tree"` into `["apple", "tree"]`. I recommend having your code print the current value of `words` after every operation you're doing, and look at the patterns there to figure out what's going on and what you can do further.

Comment: Split will return a list, perhaps what you want is: `words += f.split(" ")`

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x.replace("_", " "), f.split()))` This gives a list, instead of an append do concatenation (with +)

Comment: Seems like you have multiple questions here. To get a noun list (or more generally, a part-of-speech tagger, you can look into nlp libraries like `spacy` or `nltk`

Comment: `[word for word in f.split(" ") if "_" not in word]` instead of `f.split(" ")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code stores only words without the underscore, and all in one list instead of a nested list:

```
words = []
file = open("text.txt","r")
for f in file.readlines():
    words += [i for i in f.split(" ") if not '_' in i]
print(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It works fine.

split the whole string & add only those values in the list that have not compound words(i-e those words have not `_`)

**Code :**

```
temp = """apple tree apple_tree
banana juice banana_juice
dinner time dinner_time
divorce lawyer divorce_lawyer
breakfast table breakfast_table"""

new_arr = [i for i in temp.split() if not '_' in i]
print(new_arr)
```

**Output :**

```
['apple', 'tree', 'banana', 'juice', 'dinner', 'time', 'divorce', 'lawyer', 'breakfast', 'table']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

file = ["apple tree apple_tree apple_tree_tree apple_tree_ _",
"banana juice banana_juice",
"dinner time dinner_time",
"divorce lawyer divorce_lawyer",
"breakfast table breakfast_table"]

#approach 1 - list comprehensions
words=[]
for f in file:
    words += [x for x in f.split(" ") if '_' not in x]

print(words)

#approach 2 - regular expressions
words=[]
for f in file:
    f = re.sub(r"\s*\w*_[\w_]*\s*", "", f)
    words += f.split(" ")

print(words)
```

Both of the above approaches would work.
IMO first is better(regular expressions can be costly) and also more pythonic